# Gyroscope android in a easy way

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, gyroscope

I am developing a game that need to detect if the device is moving up or down to move up the character or move down, for that I am using gyroscope( If there is a better way please correct me)

But the gyroscope is very complicated for me( since I dont understand so much of phisyc) so I dont know how to detect if the device is movin up or down with the data that It give to me,

How I can detect it with these values?

```
float axisX = event.values[0];
float axisY = event.values[1];
float axisZ = event.values[2];
```

Comment: Correcting you: a gyroscope measures the rotation of the device. Motion along the up/down/left/right axis is not visible in those values. You'll probably want some acceleration based sensor: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html  - ps, install a tool like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miian.android.sensors and look at the values change when you move it the way you want it if you don't understand tham

Answer (score 1):

The gyroscope doesn't detect motion but rotation, so if you'd like to know if the device is being turned up or down, you can do this with the gyroscope.
Which axis is relevant for you depends on if your app is in horizontal or portrait mode.
For landscape a positive y means turning up and a negative y means turning down.
In portrait a negative x means up and a positive x down.